# How to scrape innerHTML using Selenium to get NFL betting data?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am new to coding and still learning Selenium. My hope is to scrape the NFL QB data for Passing Yards.

I am looking for the following data:

1) The QB's full name (Drew Brees, for example)

2) The line (308.5, for example)

3) The data for the last 5 games (349, 184, 311, 228, 287, for example)

You can see the QB's NAMES and LINES below.

[image]

I am looking for the full names, though. Instead of D. Brees I am looking for Drew Brees. In order to find the full names and the data for the last 5 games I need to click on the name D. Brees to access the pop up screen.

[image]

Here is an example of the output I am looking for:

```
Player                Line              Last 5 Games 

Drew Brees             308.5              349, 184, 311, 228, 287
Jacoby Brissett        230.5              251, 319, 129, 148, 59
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.betonline.ag/sportsbook/player-props")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"builder")))
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@class='one-third one-third-remove']//a[./b[contains(.,'Over / Under')]]"))).click()
time.sleep(2)

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[ng-if='selected.league']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@ng-repeat='league in leagues']/a[.//span[text()='NFL']]"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[ng-if^='selected.game']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li/a[.//div[text()='All Available']]"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(.,'Passing Yards')]"))).click()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any input that you may offer.

Comment: What is your question, what’s the problem?

Comment: I do not know how to grab the data I listed above.. The QB's full name, the line, and the last 5 days of data.

Comment: What did you try? You may be better served by a Selenium or web scraping tutorial/guide.

Comment: the best way to do this is through their API. I can give you an example, however the NFL player props isn't up for next week yet.

Comment: The data is available now @chitown88

Comment: @AbleArcher, I'll have to catch it next week, as I'm away from my computer today. Do they always post it the Sunday early morning? Or does it become available on Friday and/or Saturday?

Comment: @AbleArcher if I can't get it for NFL, I can quickly show you how to do it with NBA, then it'll just be a matter of changing a few things around. But will have to wait til later this afternoon when I get home to my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can grab the data from the API. The key is to get the playerId numbers so that you can pass that in as a parameter to get the last 5 games stats. Then it's just a matter of flattening out the nested json response to construct a table. It'll actually pull more than just the passing yards here, but hard coded to construct the table you requested. (You can manipulate the code a bit though to get what you want):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re


def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out




url = 'https://betbuilder.digitalsportstech.com/api/feed'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'betType': 'in,18,19',
'isActive': '1',
'limit': '9999',
'sb': 'betonline',
'tz': '0'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()   

# Get the player IDs
bets = []
for each in jsonData['data']:
    if 'Passing Yards' in each['statistic']['title']:
        bets.append(each)

playerDict = {}
for each in bets:
    if each['player1']['id'] not in playerDict.keys():
        playerDict[each['player1']['id']] = {'name':each['player1']['name'],
                                              'line':each['markets'][0]['value']}

# Get last 5 game stats
url = 'https://betbuilder.digitalsportstech.com/api/player-stats' 
for playerId in playerDict:
    payload = {
                'playerId': playerId,
                'sb': 'betonline',
                'tz': '0'}

    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    stats =  jsonData['data'][0]
    flat = flatten_json(stats)

    results = pd.DataFrame()
    special_cols = []

    columns_list = list(flat.keys())
    for item in columns_list:
        try:
            row_idx = re.findall(r'\_(\d+)\_', item )[0]
        except:
            special_cols.append(item)
            continue
        column = re.findall(r'\_\d+\_(.*)', item )[0]
        column = column.replace('_', '')

        row_idx = int(row_idx)
        value = flat[item]

        results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

    for item in special_cols:
        results[item] = flat[item]

    playerDict[playerId]['Last 5 Games'] = list(results['statisticspassing-yards'])


# Create the table   
df = pd.DataFrame()
for k, v in playerDict.items():
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([v]), sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
                          Last 5 Games   line           name
0  [207.0, 242.0, 276.0, 319.0, 220.0]  250.5   Kirk Cousins
1  [203.0, 195.0, 243.0, 104.0, 233.0]  244.5  Aaron Rodgers
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir @chitown88 for your beautiful explanation. It will take me some time to study this. I will learn a lot and for that I am truly grateful! =)

Comment: Ya it’s slightly tricky in that you need to get those player ids, and then learn what the query parameters mean (for example I don’t know what bet type 18 versus 19 is, and it doesn’t really matter in that you’ll get what you need. But if you wanted to start getting more specific in the data you’re trying to pull, it could be important). But you just have to play around with it and investigate. And actually, I’ll look and see if they have api doc that explains all that.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for taking the time to explain this @chitown88.  I was curious how you found the correct api. I used the inspect option, then network, then XHR. I did see some similar urls but not sure how to find the specific url that you found. I also have no experience trying to flatten json. I will look into this more.

Comment: There really isn’t an easy way, and it’s not the same everytime. Basically requires a bunch of clicking around until you find what it is that you’re looking for. The more you do it though, the better you’ll get of finding it quickly or easily eliminate the places not to look. After that, just takes a little trial and error to zero in. As far as flattening the json, pandas has json normalize function. However, it doesn’t work well on nested json. So you have to find additional way (hence the additional function flatten it completely then building a table)

Comment: Do you have any tips on finding apis? I tried copying and pasting the url "https://betbuilder.digitalsportstech.com/api/player-stats" to examine the player ids you mentioned but received this message {"errors":"Invalid request"}. Please forgive my ignorance. I am new coding and have so much to learn. Also, are you ever interested in working on coding projects? If so, is there a good way to contact you? Thank you again for your time and expertise @chitown88. You have inspired me to learn more about this subject. =)

Comment: Ty sir @chitown88! The more I look into this answer the more I can appreciate the work you did. Truly amazing! =)